# Java functional programming random int stream math abs not working

Tags: java, random, java-8, java-stream, integer-overflow

I have the following code:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamIntReduce
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt())
                .limit(100000)
                .map(x -> Math.abs(x))
                .reduce((a,b) -> {
                    System.out.println(a);
                    System.out.println(b);
                    return a + b;
                })
                .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I use `.map(x -> Math.abs(x))` to convert negative numbers to positive. Why is it that my output `System.out.println(a);` and `System.out.println(b);` still contains negative numbers?

```
-1293102468
2036920025
743817557
939157978
1682975535
1444066960
-1167924801
1361593362
193668561
1764534904
1958203465
739693193
-1597070638
```

Comment: Integer overflow...sum of two max integers

Comment: @AjayReddy Not necessarily **max integers**. Actually they both may be much lower than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: ya....I was just giving one easy example to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes here:

The method `.nextInt()` returns both positive and negative numbers. If you need only positives, then call the overloaded method `.nextInt(bound)` with a positive bound. Thus you can drop mapping `x -> Math.abs(x)`.

---

The `Integer` type is limited in Java. It has strictly defined upper and lower bounds:

```
public static final int MIN_VALUE = -2147483648;
public static final int MAX_VALUE = 2147483647;
```

When you add two numbers and the sum is bigger than `MAX_VALUE`, then the bits `overflow` and the sign bit gets changed. Thus summing two big `Integer` numbers may lead to a negative result in Java (and not only).

---

If you still want to sum up the numbers like that, you can use `BigInteger` instead of `Integer`.

The modified code looks like:

```
 Stream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
       .limit(100000)
       .map(BigInteger::valueOf)
       .reduce((a, b) -> {
                  System.out.println(a);
                  System.out.println(b);
                  return a.add(b);
       })
       .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Or use [`new Random().longs(100000, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#longs-long-long-long-) in the first place. `longs` returns a sized stream, which is more efficient than `generate`+`limit`, then, no boxing to `Integer` and also converting to `BigInteger` isn’t necessary, as `long` is already sufficient.